# Diameter of a binary tree in Java

Tags: java, tree

I wrote this to calculate the diameter of a binary tree. Are there any cases for which this code might fail?

```
import java.util.*;

class Node {
        int key;
        Node left,right;
        public Node(int item){
            key=item;
            left=right=null;
        }
}
class BST {
    Node root;
    int diameter=0;
    public int diameter(BST t,Node root){
        int left, right;
        if(root == null) 
            return 0;
        left = diameter(t,root.left);
        right = diameter(t,root.right);
        if(left + right + 1> diameter)
            diameter = left + right + 1;
        if(t.root==root) 
            return diameter;
        return Math.max(left, right)+1;
    }


    public void insert(int item){

    if(root == null){
        root = new Node(item);
        return;
    }
    Node p,parent;p=root;parent=null;
    while(p != null){
            parent = p;
            if(item < p.key)
                p=p.left;
            else if(item > p.key)
                p=p.right;
            else 
                return;
        }
        Node z = new Node(item);
        if(item < parent.key) parent.left = z;
        else parent.right = z;
}

    public static void main(String args[]){
        BST newtree = new BST();

        newtree.insert(150);
        newtree.insert(120);
        newtree.insert(130);
        newtree.insert(90);
        newtree.insert(100);
        newtree.insert(140);
        newtree.insert(110);
        newtree.insert(100);
        newtree.insert(132);
        newtree.insert(138);
        newtree.insert(134);
        newtree.insert(136);
        newtree.insert(170);

        System.out.println("Diameter is "+newtree.diameter(newtree,newtree.root));


    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! You might want to include your actual `BST` class. As it stands reviewers are left making a ton of assumptions, which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Doesn't handle remove

This solution doesn't handle the `remove` case.  If you add the ability to remove nodes from the tree, you'll have to include logic to clear the existing diameter value.

#### What if `t` is not `this`

You can

```
BST caller = new BST();
BST traversed = new BST();

// put stuff in both

System.out.println(caller.diameter(caller, caller.root));
System.out.println(caller.diameter(traversed, traversed.root));
System.out.println(caller.diameter(caller, caller.root));
```

If `caller` has a larger diameter than `traversed`, the second call will return the wrong value.  If `traversed` has the larger diameter, the third call will return the wrong value.

And if you

#### It's confusing

Your `diameter` method sometimes returns the diameter and sometimes returns the height.  What happens if you

```
caller.diameter(caller, traversed.root);
```

It will return the height.

If you do

```
caller.diameter(caller, caller.root.right);
```

It will return one more than either the height of the left side or the diameter of the right subtree.

As a general rule, you don't want callers to have to get information from the object in order to call an object method.  Really, this acts more like a class method than an object method.  The only object variable that it accesses is the `diameter`.  And this is entirely fixable.  Consider

```
public int diameter() {
    return diameter(this, root);
}
```

Now you can call it like `caller.diameter()` and everything will just work.

But I think that I'd go beyond that and instead do

```
public int getDiameter() {
    return root.getDiameter();
}
```

Then have the `insert` and `remove` code set the diameters of each affected node on any change.  Same thing for height.